# How to fix failed assertions on raw string literals

Tags: go

I'm writing unit tests for a restful api and want to ensure that am getting the expected response. How do I get rid of the "\n" at the end of my expected string literal?

I am using the stetchr's testify package. I have tried to use strings TrimSuffix, TrimRight functions but in vain.

```
func TestGetConfig(t *testing.T) {

    testServer := initTestServer(t)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "/api/config", nil)
    if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
    }

    rr := httptest.NewRecorder()
    handler := http.HandlerFunc(testServer.getConfig)
    handler.ServeHTTP(rr, req)

    //Check the status code is what we expect
    if status := rr.Code; status != http.StatusOK {
    t.Errorf("handler returned wrong status code: got %v 
want %v", status, http.StatusOK)
    }


    //Check the response body is what we expect.

 expected := `{"domain":"","ip":"","redirect_key":"mj","redirect_url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ","verification_key":"yp","verification_token":"5a62"}`

    expected = strings.TrimSuffix(expected, "\n")
    assert.Equal(t, rr.Body.String(), expected)
```

}

I expect the tests to pass but instead it fails and gives this as the output.

```
Error Trace:    config_test.go:94
                    Error:          Not equal:
                                    expected: "{\"domain\":\"\",\"ip\":\"\",\"redirect_key\":\"mj\",\"redirect_url\":\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ\",\"verification_key\":\"yp\",\"verification_token\":\"5a62\"}\n"
                                    actual  : "{\"domain\":\"\",\"ip\":\"\",\"redirect_key\":\"mj\",\"redirect_url\":\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ\",\"verification_key\":\"yp\",\"verification_token\":\"5a62\"}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trimming a non-existent `"\n"` character off of your `expected` string instead of the actual response body.

But the simpler way is to just include the `"\n"` in the `expected` string. That way the expected string will in fact be what you are expecting.

Comment: Agreed. By trimming, your tests will pass even if your code starts returning "{...}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n", which you probably don't really want.

Comment: Damn.I didn't realize this as i had my parameters passed in the wrong order.

Answer (score 2):

The order of parameters is wrong.

It is

```
assert.Equal(t, rr.Body.String(), expected)
```

It should be

```
assert.Equal(t, expected, rr.Body.String())
```

See [Equal method documentatin](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#Equal)

You are trimming wrong value.

Comment: Oh thanks it was a typoh on my end did change to the right parameter ordering.I was trimming the expected value instead of the actual response body.